# Linking ktor and kotlinx.coroutines results in undefined symbols

Tags: ios, kotlinx.coroutines, ktor, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to link my Kotlin/Native project as a framework for iOS. The Kotlin code compiles just fine, but when the linker is run, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractContinuation.getResult$kotlinx-coroutines-core-native()kotlin.Any?", referenced from:
      _kfun:io.ktor.client.engine.ios.IosClientEngine.execute(io.ktor.client.call.HttpClientCall;io.ktor.client.request.HttpRequestData)io.ktor.client.call.HttpEngineCall in combined.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors
```

I have tried changing the platform from `iosX64` to `iosArm64` but it results in the same error. Here is my gradle file for reference just in case I'm missing a dependency.

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.11'
    id 'kotlinx-serialization' version '1.3.0'
}

ext {
    ktor_version = '1.0.1'
    coroutines_version = '1.1.0'
    serialization_version = '0.9.1'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

configurations {
    compilerPlugin
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

}

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
        // This preset is for iPhone emulator
        // Switch here to presets.iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
        fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client:$ktor_version")
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common'
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
            }
        }
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios_debug_ios_x64:$ktor_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"
            }
        }
        iosTest {
        }
        configure([ios_x86_64Main, ios_arm64Main]) {
            dependsOn iosMain
        }
    }
}

// This task attaches native framework built from ios module to Xcode project
// (see iosApp directory). Don't run this task directly,
// Xcode runs this task itself during its build process.
// Before opening the project from iosApp directory in Xcode,
// make sure all Gradle infrastructure exists (gradle.wrapper, gradlew).
task copyFramework {
    def buildType = project.findProperty("kotlin.build.type") ?: "DEBUG"
    def target = project.findProperty("kotlin.target") ?: "ios"
    dependsOn "link${buildType.toLowerCase().capitalize()}Framework${target.capitalize()}"

    doLast {
        def srcFile = kotlin.targets."$target".compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)
        def targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
        copy {
            from srcFile.parent
            into targetDir
            include 'app.framework/**'
            include 'app.framework.dSYM'
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This looks like a linker error. Do you know if `ktor` is a static lib or a dylib/framework? If it's the latter, you'll need to link it as well in your main app.

Comment: Here's an example project that is linking to `ktor` and running on iOS: https://github.com/adrianbukros/github-multiplatform-example

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was actually able to solve this issue by updating from version `1.0.1` of `ktor` to `1.1.1`. Looks like the API changed in `kotlinx.coroutines` and `ktor` needed to updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iosMain` Ktor dependency seems wrong. Try setting it like this:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-ios:$ktor_version"
```